# Cannot Seem to Find issue

Tags: python, html, flask

I have been working on my company website in flask and I am trying to make the contact page work with URL_FOR, however it does not seem to be accepting it. I am not sure where I have gone wrong with the code. I am sure I am missing something or did something wrong. I have been working at this most of the morning. If anyone is able to help out that would be awesome..

Thank you in advance.
Michael

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import csv


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/<string:page_name>')
def html_page(page_name):
    return render_template(page_name)

# def write_to_file(data):
#   with open('database.txt', mode='a') as database:
#       name = data["name"]
#       email = data["email"]
#       message = data["message"]
#       file = database.write(f'\n{name},{email},{message}')

def write_to_csv(data):
    with open('database.csv', newline="", mode='a') as database2:
        name = data["name"]
        email = data["email"]
        message = data["message"]
        csv_writer = csv.writer(database2, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        csv_writer.writerow([name, email, message])

@app.route('/contact', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def contact():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form.to_dict()
        write_to_csv(data)
        return redirect('/sent.html')
    else:
        return 'Something went wrong. Try again..!'
```

html contact page is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Guru Coding | Contact Us</title>
    <meta name="description"
        content="Guru Coding services. We design and develop high quality websites tailored to your needs">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="static/assets//favicon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/style/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Navigation container -->
    <nav id='navMenu'>

        <!-- Top Nav wrapper -->
        <div class="top__nav__wrapper">
            <!-- Logo container -->
            <a href="index.html">
                <div class="logo__container" title='Guru Coding logo'>
                    <!-- Logo -->
                    <img class='logo' src="static/assets/favicon.png" loading='lazy' alt="Guru Coding logo">
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Nav list container -->
        <div class="nav__list__container">
            <ul>
                <li title='Home'><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li title='Services'><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                <!-- <li title='Portfolio'><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li> -->
                <li title='Our Team'><a href="team.html">Our Team</a></li>
                <li title='Contact' class='page--active'><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Burger icon container -->
    <div class="burger__container" id='navIcon'>
        <!-- Burger lines -->
        <div class="burger__line line1"></div>
        <div class="burger__line line2"></div>
        <div class="burger__line line3"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Header container -->
    <header>

        <!-- Header text container -->
        <div class="text__container">

            <!-- Header title container -->
            <div class="header__container header__container--contact">
                <h1 class='highlight__title'>Contact Us</h1>
            </div>

            <!-- Header text container -->
            <div class="header__text">
                <!-- Header text -->
                <h4>You have a business idea and you want to make it a <span class="highlight__text">real
                        thing?</span>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    Or maybe you want a simple website for your <span class="highlight__text">personal needs?</span>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    Whatever it is you
                    are looking for, you can surely find it at
                    <span class="highlight__text">Guru Coding!</span>
                </h4>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Scroll icon container -->
        <div class="icon__container">
            <!-- Scroll icon -->
            <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Section 1 container -->
    <section class='section--1 section--contact'>
        <h2 class='section__title'>Get in touch</h2>

        <!-- Social Media icons container -->
        <div class="social__icons__container">

            <!-- Twitter link and icon -->
            <a href="https://twitter.com/GuruCodingCo" title='Guru Coding Twitter' target="_blank">
                <i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i>
            </a>

            <!-- Facebook link and icon -->
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Guru-Coding-Company-101417465307382" title='Guru Coding Facebook'
                target="_blank">
                <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Contact form container -->
        <div class="contact__form__container">
            <form method="post" action="{{ url_for ('sent') }}" id='contactForm'>
                <div class="input__container">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id='name' placeholder='Name'>
                </div>
                <div class="input__container">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" id='email' placeholder='Email'>
                </div>
                <div class="input__container">
                    <textarea type="text" placeholder='Enter your message'></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="button__container">
                    <button type='submit' id='submitButton' style='color: whitesmoke'>Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Footer section -->
    <footer>

        <!-- Footer left -->
        <div class="footer--left">
            <p>Guru Coding 2021</p>
            <br>
            <a href="sitemap.html" class='highlight__link' title='Sitemap'>View Sitemap</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Footer right -->
        <div class="footer--right">
            <p>Website created by
                <a title='Contact Author' class='highlight__link' href="mailto:lpytel16@gmail.com">Lukasz</a>
            </p>
        </div>

    </footer>

    <!-- Script tags -->
    <script src="static/app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be more specific. What do you mean "not accepting it". Post any errors for example so people can come and better assist. Thanks

Comment: JCooke, It was a simple error on my part. I used sent instead I should have used contact. The below answer helped me to see the fault I had made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is you dont have a route for `'sent'` anywhere in your code so I think you meant `'contact'` for the form post method.